# How to reverse values in a dictionary or list?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a dictionary

```
{1:’one’,2:’two’}
```

I want to reverse it using a function and became to the following

```
{‘1:’eno’,2:’owt’ }
```

How can I do it?

Similarly, if I have a list or tuple like `[15,49]`, how can I convert it to `[94,51]`?

Answer (score 12):

You can use a simple dict comprehension, using the fact that `string[::-1]` reverses a string:

```
>>> d = {1: "one", 2: "two"}
>>> {x: v[::-1] for x, v in d.items()}
{1: 'eno', 2: 'owt'}
```

You could also define a function:

```
def reverse_values(dct):
    for key in dct:
       dct[key] = dct[key][::-1]
```

Which will alter the values in the same dict.

```
>>> reverse_values(d)
>>> d
{1: 'eno', 2: 'owt'}
```

---

For converting list of type `[15,49]` to `[94, 51]`, you can try the snippet below (this will work for lists of type `[12, 34, 56, 78]` to `[87, 65, 43, 21]` as well):

```
>>> l = [15,49]
>>> [int(str(x)[::-1]) for x in l[::-1]]
[94, 51]
```

Comment: another Q if i have a list or tuple  I want to become

[15,49] => [94,51] ,

(15,49) = >(94,51)

How could I write the function?

Answer (score 0):

For your [question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29981473/python-how-to-reverse-values-in-a-dictionary#comment48082692_29981488), use the following:

Given that `[::-1]` reverses the string, we can convert each number to a string, reverse each item, convert back to an integer, then reverse the **entire** list:

```
>>> lst = [15, 49]
>>> [int(str(item)[::-1]) for item in lst][::-1]
[94, 51]
>>>
```